# Python built-in max(), when 2 values are the same which one gets picked?

Tags: python, python-2.x

I have a code that processes data based on some dates. 
Lets say:

```
case1:

values1 with date1 = '2002-02-01'
values2 with date2 = '2004-02-01'

case2:

values1 with date1 ='2001-01-01'
values2 with date2 ='2001-01-01'
```

I need to get the most recent record. Everything works fine when my values have different dates, but when records have the same dates `max(date1, date2)`.
**Question. Which max value is returned when the values are equal, like in case 2?**

Comment: Does it matter? The values are equal, after all.

Comment: *"If multiple items are maximal, the function returns the first one encountered."* Straight from [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max).

Comment: @MartijnPieters Maybe if you plan to mutate the return value (if that's possible).

Comment: @timgeb: sure, but the OP has given an example with strings, immutable objects.

Comment: @Marjin `is` does not equal `==`

Comment: @MartijnPieters, it matters because values are different.

Comment: @oshaiken: no, they are not when they are equal. Or are you saying that your actual usecase involves mutable objects?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I meant in my specific case, where I get values by dates, and my values are different only the dates are the same. Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For multiple values that are all the maximum, the first such value is returned:

```
>>> class Equal:
...     def __init__(self, id):
...         self.id = id
...     def __repr__(self):
...         return f"Equal({self.id!r})"
...     def __gt__(self, other):
...         return False
...
>>> max([Equal(1), Equal(2), Equal(3)])
Equal(1)
```

This is explicitly [documented](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max):

> If multiple items are maximal, the function returns the first one encountered.

Comment: Is it true for python2.6 ?

Comment: @oshaiken: yes, the algorithm didn't change from Python 2 to 3.

Comment: Thank you! I read the old docs and did not see it mentioning it.

Answer (score 1):

"If multiple items are maximal, the function returns the first one encountered."

Source: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max

Comment: Is it true for python2.6 ?